# Determine Control's 'AutoSize'-size at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I want to layout controls during runtime (dynamically created). For the purpose of this question, let's restrict to a Button control. I want to set the control's properties (such as `Text`) and then determine the minimum size for the control for it to display properly; the size that setting `AutoSize = true` would give. In C# example code, with `GetAutoSizeSize` being this minimum size:

```
Button button = new Button();
this.Controls.Add(button);

button.Text = "Example";
button.Size = GetAutoSizeSize(button);
button.Location = /* Some calculation based on button.Size */
```

---

#### Possible solution: AutoSize

One can set `button.AutoSize = true` and `button.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeNode.GrowAndShrink`. After that, the `button.Size` can be fetched, after which `AutoSize` can be turned off and the control size can be changed.

Potential issues:

- It looks odd and I can't help but feel that this could easily break, but maybe I am wrong?

#### Possible solution: GetPreferredSize

`button.GetPreferredSize` can be used to get a size that the control wants to be.

Problems with this:

- Its usage is internal and/or meant for flow layout.
- `GetPreferredSize` takes a suggested size as a parameter, so one needs to guess at what would be appropriate.
- The size returned is wrong, in that it returns the 'comfy' size of a control, which can be much larger than the minimum size that `AutoSize` gives.

---

**EDIT:** From the comments and some trial-and-error, I was able to conclude that the problems I originally listed with the AutoSize-method were due to needing both the control to be added to the control collection first and `AutoSizeMode` set to `GrowAndShrink`.

I would like to know if there is a function (and/or more 'robust' way) of determining the AutoSize-size: a function like `GetPreferredSize` that returns the size without actually having to toggle `AutoSize`.

Comment: Hmm, you are just doing it the wrong way around.  It can only be auto-sized *after* it is added to the parent's Controls collection.  Not until then can basic stuff like dpi-awareness and layout constraints be sorted out.  Don't put too much trust into magic unseen code doing everything you like it to do.

Comment: @HansPassant I modified the example code to first add and then calculate, as this was not meant to be the relevant part of the question.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this either.  Maybe you should just use a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: You made the question nonsensical by editing but still including the phrase "wait for it to update its size".  Only guess I have left is that you are still hoping for the man-behind-the-curtain taking care of everything.  Winforms is first and foremost invested in reproducing the layout that was established at design-time.  There is no real substitute for not designing your UI.  Of course there isn't.

Comment: The entire gist of my question is "Each control knows what its AutoSize size will be; how can I get that size?". Either that question doesn't make sense, somehow, or I was not clear in my post?

Answer (score -1):

This works when you are drawing on a control.

```
String sMyString = "this is my string";
Font fntFont = new Font("Arial", 8);
SizeF sfMySize = new SizeF(5,5);
sfMySize = System.Graphics.MeasureString(sMyString, fntFont, sfMySize);
```

This will give you the dimensions of the bounding box around the control text. You would have to work out the appropriate buffer around the text to set the button size.